# I just want to know how can I use tailwind with single-spa

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, tailwind-css, micro-frontend, single-spa

How can I create a global style guide that can provide tailwind functionality to all my frameworks connected with root config

Comment: I found this repo. I have followed it but the tailwind in other micro apps is not working. Were you able to find any other solution? 
https://github.com/react-microfrontends/styleguide

Comment: Any updates here?